# How do I remove the '.php' extension from URLs?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, file-extension

This is where the PHP files are:

ts1.WEBSITENAMEHERE.biz/cp/

The .htaccess file is also in this folder.
I want to remove the '.php' from 'FILENAME.PHP'.

This is my current '.htaccess' file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /cp
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

But it is not working. Why is this?

Comment: if you can't get ANY .htaccess rules working, be sure to check in the site root folder's <directory> settings and make sure AllowOverride is set to "all" and not "none" (or that AllowOverride is missing). This is usually in httpd.conf although it can also in in vhosts.conf if you have multiple sites http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: guess this will work in your case `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cp/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L]
```

Comment: This is rewriting the index directory to return an error.
For example: /cp/.php
I want: /cp/ <-- Nothing extra showing files or FILENAME as index.
I want it to either show the files in that directory or have the index be FILENAME.php.

Comment: @Aaron Walker: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: Thanks zerkms! That was a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in the DocumentRoot dir.
Add the following code in that file...

```
##############
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [R]
#############
```

mod_rewrite should be enabled for this to work.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteBase /cp
    RewriteRule ^(.*) $1.php
```

I use this checker: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be

Comment: It would cause infinite rewrite loop

Comment: it would append `.php` on `filename.php`, so it would be `filename.php.php` at the end.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: not actually, it would append `.php` even to `filename.php.php` getting `filename.php.php.php` and will never reach the end

Comment: @zerkms... hm, not so sure, did not test, but i think it would execute `^(.*)` pattern and then go to `$1.php` part. maybe you're right, but certainly this doesn't remove `.php` from filename.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace." `mod_rewrite` execution loop rewrites the url as long as urls in the begin and in the end of each iteration loop are different. In this case - they are, so - it is infinite loop :-)