# Apache request page without PHP extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to request a file with it's .php extension, so for example, instead of going to, `http://example.com/about.php` the user would only need to type `http://example.com/about`.

I have tried the following but just get a 404 page,

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]`

Comment: definately possible, but be careful you don't run into conflicts with directories

Comment: yes, I have also tried it by going to `example.com/index` to the load the root of the site and 404 also.

Comment: @kalpaitch conflicts, do you mean that is trying to read my URL segment as directory? How would I get around this?

Comment: @sico87 you won't. That's what the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`stands for - in words it means "if the request filename isn't a `d`irectory" then apply the `RewriteRule`. Are you also sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules should work if the requested file (after rewriting) exists. For example the page `/phpinfo` was requested and the file `/phpinfo.php` exists. But the same rules will create an infinite loop if the file (after rewriting) does not exist, for example:

- `/phpinfo` matches the RewriteRule and both RewriteCond are satisfied, result will be `/phpinfo.php`
- `L` flag stops current iteration but since filename has changed, another iteration is required
- `/phpinfo.php` matches the RewriteRule and both RewriteCond are satisfied, result will be `/phpinfo.php.php`
- repeat until mod_rewrite gives up

There are few workarounds, the simplest one is to tweak your `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1.php [QSA,L]
```

If you continuously get 404 error even for simple rewrite rules, chances are that your rewrite rules are not being processed by Apache. A possible reason is that that `AllowOverride` is set to `None` in server configuration file (`httpd.conf`). Change that to `AllowOverride FileInfo` and restart Apache.

Answer (score 2):

You need to exclude .php from the url because otherwise you can get an infinite loop and it result in an url like this .php.php.php.php. But the idea is good and it works.

1. [How do I remove the '.php' extension from URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042874/how-do-i-remove-the-php-extension-from-urls/11042978#11042978)